# PostgreSQL: How to create array with empty string in PreparedStatement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have test table with one empty name value:

```
create table tmp_table_test (id serial, name varchar(100));

insert into tmp_table_test (name) values ('');
insert into tmp_table_test (name) values ('a');
insert into tmp_table_test (name) values ('b');
```

When I run this query:

```
SelectSQLPrepared("SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name IN ('', 'a') order by 1;")
```

I see two records.

Now I want to change it into PreparedStatement and see the same records, but I don't know how to insert empty string into array.

I tried

```
SelectSQLPrepared("SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name IN (SELECT unnest(?::text[])) order by 1;", "{'', a}")
```

or:

```
SelectSQLPrepared("SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name = ANY (?::text[])", "{'', a}")
```

but it returned only record with `a` name.

I tried:

```
SelectSQLPrepared("SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name IN (SELECT unnest(?::text[])) order by 1;", "{, a}")
```

but it gives error:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "{, a}"
```

The only query that I invented looks strange:

```
SelectSQLPrepared("SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name IN (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(?, ','))) order by 1;", ",a")
```

There is `,a` as parameter to `string_to_array()` which gives me array with an empty string and `a`, but there I do not know how to escape colons which can be in input values.

Is there any solution to use prepared statement with IN clause to search for empty string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array directly by using the `ANY` operator (to which the `IN`gets rewritten anyway) and cast it in the prepared statement source:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tmp_table_test WHERE name = any(cast ? as text[]) order by 1
```

The pass a String literal like `{"", a}`, e.g.:

```
pstmt.setString(1, "{\"\", a}"
```

Comment: I'm surprised I have to use `"` instead of "normal" string delimeters: `'`, but it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a array constructor `ARRAY`

```
postgres=# SELECT ARRAY[''];
┌───────┐
│ array │
╞═══════╡
│ {""}  │
└───────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT ARRAY['', 'a'];
┌────────┐
│ array  │
╞════════╡
│ {"",a} │
└────────┘
(1 row)
```